# Stop and Restart game in Processing on button press

Tags: processing

I'm currently working on a small game to learn Processing.

I want my game to stop when I press "Stop" and want my game to reset/restart when "Stop" changed to Start.

(When I click on the button, it changes Stop to Start and back to Stop etc etc. (so basically, I have 1 'button')

I'm struggling and can't find a solution on internet / stackoverflow so maybe someone can help me?

(@ mousePressed's if else I need the 'stop and restart function')

```java
float x = width/2;
float speed = 2;

boolean textHasBeenClicked = false;

int aantalRaak = 0; 
int aantalMis = 0;
int positieText = 20;

void setup() {
  background(0);
  size(600,500);
}

void draw() {
  clear();
  move();
  display();  
  smooth();
  //Scoreboard bovenaan
  fill(255);
  textSize(20);
  textAlign(LEFT);
  text("Aantal geraakt: " + aantalRaak,0, positieText); text("Aantal gemist: " + aantalMis, width/2, positieText);

  //button onderaan
      fill(0,255,0);
      rect(width/2-40, height-40, 100, 50);// draw anyway...

} 

void mousePressed() {
    // toggle 
    textHasBeenClicked = ! textHasBeenClicked;
    fill(0);
    if (textHasBeenClicked) {
        // display text 2
        textSize(30);
        textAlign(CENTER);
        text("Stop" , width/2,height-10); 

    }
    else  {
        // display text 1
        textSize(30);
        textAlign(CENTER);
        text("Start" , width/2,height-10); 
        }
}



void move() {
  x = x + speed;
  if (x > width) {
    x = 0;
  }
}

void display(){
  //schietschijf
  float y = height/2;
  noStroke();
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  ellipse(x, y, 40, 40);   

  fill(255);
  ellipse(x, y, 30, 30);

  fill(255, 0, 0);
  ellipse(x, y, 20, 20);  

  fill(255);
  ellipse(x, y, 10, 10);  
}
```

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: Did one of the answers solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to [break your problem down into smaller steps](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and take those steps on one at a time. You're really asking two questions:

- How do I show a stop button that turns into a start button?
- How do I reset a sketch?

For the first question, you can create a boolean variable. Use that variable in your `draw()` function, and then modify that variable in the `mousePressed()` function.

```
boolean running = false;

void draw() {
  fill(0);
  if (running) {
    background(255, 0, 0);
    text("Stop", 25, 25);
  } else {
    background(0, 255, 0);
    text("Start", 25, 25);
  }
}

void mousePressed() {
  running = !running;
}
```

Then for resetting the sketch, you can create a function that changes all of your variables back to their default values. Here's a simple example:

```
float circleY;

void setup() {
  size(100, 500);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  circleY++;

  ellipse(width/2, circleY, 20, 20);
}

void reset() {
  circleY = 0;
}

void mousePressed() {
  reset();
}
```

Try to work from small examples like this instead of your full program, and post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you get stuck. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

You may consider implementing a while loop. I don't know what library you're using for input, so I can't tell you exactly what to do. But something along the lines of:

```
while(!InputReceived) {
    if(CheckForMouseInput()) // Assuming CheckForMouseInput returns true if input was detected
        break // Input was detected, now do stuff based on that.
    else {
        // Must #include <thread> and #include <chrono>
        // Wait a bit...

        continue; // Jump back to the top of the loop, effectively restarting it.
    }
```

Would probably suit your needs. That is what I would do, at least. After the loop breaks, the game is effectively restarted, and you can do whatever you need to do based on that.

Comment: The question is about java and not C++

Comment: @Rabbid76 The exact same concept still applies.

Comment: Do you think the questioner can deal with `std::chrono`? [Processing](https://processing.org/) is something completely different in compare to C++

Comment: @Rabbid76 Probably not, I changed my answer to reflect this. Thank you for your feedback, I believe that this code will now work for him. It's not so much for him to copy and paste, more for him to understand the necessary steps to do what he needs to do. Forgive me, I've never heard of processing and mistook the program for C++ and some library, since the syntax is very similar.